# What is the correct equation for "Normal distribution function of continuous random variable"?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, visualization

I was reading a book and came across with a equation which gives the normal distribution function of continuous random variable. It was used in a software called `RapidMiner` to visualize data distribution.

$f\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi \sigma } }}{e^{\frac{{{{\left( {x - \mu } \right)}^2}}}{{2{\sigma ^2}}}}}$ , where $x$ is random variable, $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, and $\mu$ is the mean of the distribution.

I got badly confused, as it is different and not same as what I learnt from textbook or wikipedia, which is:

$f\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}{e^{ - \frac{{{{\left( {x - \mu } \right)}^2}}}{{2{\sigma ^2}}}}}$ where the symbols mean the same.

**I have questions:**

1. is the equation in the book correct?
2. if so, could you please walk me through how could the equation be correct? Maybe give me some keyword for searching.
3. if wrong, could you tell me why?

Finally the book luckily provide a on-line reading site: http://www.learnpredictiveanalytics.com/preview.html . The context of the equation of my question is on Page 51, right below figure 3.9.

Thank you.

Comment: Only the second mentioned in your question is okay. The first clearly differs from the second, so is not okay.

Comment: Thank you for your support after all I was not sure whether it was another version of the PDF of normal distribution

Answer (score 0):

Deal all, I just noticed someone answered my question but soon deleted. She/he mentioned that performing integral calculation will tell the differernce. And actually it works and I realized and strongly believed that the equation on the book was wrong.

I input the equations to an online integral calculator (well, I know it was an bad idea). And found the result is "The integral is divergent" while the second one yields "1".

Problem solved.